# Bash~ how can I make so if argument 1 contains a negative int or a string it exits

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my script, im having trouble in elif statement. I need it to exit if user enters a non negative integer as argument 1 or a string..

```
#!/bin/sh
n="0"
m="$1" 
if test $# != "2"
then
    echo "Usage: ./echon.sh <number of lines> <string>"
    exit 1
elif [ $1 -eq "[^0-9]" ] || [ $1 = "[a-zA-Z]" ]
then
    echo "./echon.sh: argument 1 must be a non-negative integer"
    exit 1
else
    while [ "$n" -lt  "$m" ]
    do
    echo "$2"
    n=$(($n + 1))
    done
fi
```

Comment: `-eq` is for numeric comparisons, not string or regexp

Comment: And `=` is for string comparison, not regexp.

Comment: I think you'd want to exit when someone enters negative number and not non-negative number.

Answer (score 2):

A quick rewrite

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo "Usage: $0 <number of lines> <string>"
elif [[ $1 != 0 && $1 != [1-9]*([0-9]) ]]; then
    echo "$0: argument 1 must be a non-negative integer"
else
    n=0
    while (( n < $1 )); do
        echo "$2"
        ((n++))
    done
fi
```

Notes

- using `[[ ... ]]` for string comparisons
- using `(( ... ))` for arithmetic expressions
- using extended globbing to match a non-negative integer (enforcing a non-zero number does not begin with 0, to avoid potential invalid octal numbers)

Comment: +1 Nice use of pattern matching with `*(...)`.  I think you can drop the `$1 != 0 &&` part.

Comment: Also, you can use `*([0-9])` without setting `extglob`.

Comment: What version of bash lets you use that syntax *without* extglob? The `$1 != 0` is required to allow "0" as a valid non-negative integer: I explicitly disallow numbers starting with "0" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `elif` line with the following:

```
elif echo $1 | grep -qv "^[0-9][0-9]*"
```